# JQuery Version Conflict with Div Search Effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".form-select.pais").change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    if (val != 'Any') {
      $("div.views-row, div.[class^='views-field-field-bank-office-pais-value-']").hide();
      $("div.views-row, div.views-field-field-bank-office-pais-value-" + val).show();
    } else {
      $("div.views-row, div.[class^='views-field-field-bank-office-pais-value-']").show();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  background-color: #ddf;
  margin: 2px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">
  <p>
    Here is a text test!
  </p>
</div>


<select id="json-one" class="form-select pais">
  <option value="Any">Any</option>
  <option value="USA">USA</option>
  <option value="Chile">Chile</option>
  <option value="Spain">Spain</option>
</select>



<div class="views-row">
  <div class="views-field-field-bank-office-pais-value-USA">
    <span class="field-content">this is div USA</span>
  </div>
  <div class="views-field-field-bank-office-pais-value-Chile">
    <span class="field-content">this is div Chile</span>
  </div>
  <div class="views-field-field-bank-office-pais-value-Spain">
    <span class="field-content">this is div Spain</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hello,

I forked a fiddle that had a sliding effect and tweaked to my linking where it hides and shows depending on selection of a drop box. The issue I have is that is hiding all the divs on the page. For example the div with the class "test" should not hide but it is happening. That was not the intended effect I had in mind. (This has been fixed)

Thanks.

This is the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select').change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    if (val != 'Any') {
      $('div:not(div.views-row, div.views-field-field-bank-office-pais-value-' + val + ')').hide();
      $("div.views-row, div.views-field-field-bank-office-pais-value-" + val).show();
    } else {
      $("div.views-row, div").show();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  background-color: #ddf;
  margin: 2px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select>
  <option value="Any">Any</option>
  <option value="USA">USA</option>
  <option value="Chile">Chile</option>
  <option value="Spain">Spain</option>
</select>

<div class="views-row">
  <div class="views-field views-field-field-bank-office-pais-value-USA">
    <span class="field-content">this is div USA</span>
  </div>
  <div class="views-field views-field-field-bank-office-pais-value-Chile">
    <span class="field-content">this is div Chile</span>
  </div>
  <div class="views-field views-field-field-bank-office-pais-value-Spain">
    <span class="field-content">this is div Spain</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

The fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/yjc8jsvw/92/

Update:
I forked the forked fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/u96xfo4x/28/

Problem I have now is that this works with jquery 1.6 but not with 2.0+ with jquery migrate.

I need assistance updating this script.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing line 5 of the JS to:

```
$('div.views-row div:not(.div-' + val + ')').hide();
```

See working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/o56g7804/1/ where the div containing the 'test' text stays put following change of the dropdown.

Comment: Thanks Ross, I made some changes to my fiddle and it worked but I noticed it is hiding those specific divs and if there are other spans then they show up. So, I modified the HTML. But I don't understand why it doesn't do the effects on the entire divs. What am I missing? Thanks again.
Updated fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/u96xfo4x/47/

Comment: Got it working Thanks! I used this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9182171/how-to-select-everything-inside-a-div-with-jquery and with what you showed me it works now.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working, I hope my suggestion helped, if so please accept this as the answer (click the tick to the left of the answer), thanks!